# Unable to call Blender to run a script

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, command-line

I'm making a website. Here php executes a blender python script. I used

```
exec('blender -p *path for script*',$output,$return)
```

And put an if to check the result. But I am unable to get desired results. Output is:

```
Array ( [0] => found bundled python: /Applications/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.79/python [1] => Saved session recovery to '/tmp/quit.blend' [2] => [3] => Blender quit )
```

I'm on macos 10.12.6. Please help me out.

Comment: That looks correct. Blender loaded ran the script and output those three lines to the console. Does it work if you run it from the command prompt? what did you want the script to do/produce?

Comment: I wanted it to auto render images and save them in a destination. Auto run script isn't working when I call it from php

Comment: but does it work when you run it manually from the command prompt? Often calling other executables from within scripts/code requires some modification to get around special character encoding, permissions etc. Prove that what you want works in the simplest situation and then build from there, I speak from experience.

Comment: It works when I do that from the command prompt

Comment: Then it is your PHP code causing the issues. check how PHP handles quotes and double quotes within strings.If you are using variables in strings just try hard coding everything for testing purposes.